# Cordova/Phonegap: Open a file from SQLite

Tags: javascript, android, file, android-sqlite, cordova-3

I have a Cordova based app that syncs some data from server to SQLite. The files are encoded to base64 and saved as text in DB. Now I need to open the files in JavaScript. There are 2 types of operation I need to do:

1. open a file with external application like PDF etc. (window.open('file://...', '_system'))
2. view a file as image in my HTML content

Do I have to save the file (with Cordova File API plugin) to SD card and link it afterwards (window.open or in IMG tag) or is there a way to do the above without saving the file to disk?